# Magento 2 - Add to cart not working after products loaded by ajax

Tags: magento2, addtocart, ajax

I have loaded products collection using ajax. My controller URL is something like this:

```
www.example.com/whoboughtthisproduct/index/getproducts
```

Now products are loading properly, but when user click on add to cart button instead of add product to cart it is redirecting user to  `www.example.com/whoboughtthisproduct/index/getproducts`

My controller code is this:

```
protected $resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
)
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute()
{
    $viewBlock = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $block = $viewBlock->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Vendor\WhoBoughtThisProduct\Block\ProductList')
        ->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml')
        ->toHtml();

    //Setting response
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
}
```

And the code where I am calling ajax is this:

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function($){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/whoboughtthisproduct/index/getproducts",
        type: "POST",
        data: "prod=<?php echo $productId; ?>",
        success: function (res) {
            if(res.indexOf("find products matching the selection") > -1){
                //if no products found then do nothing
                return;
            }

            var result = jQuery('.product-items', res).html();
            jQuery(".bought-slider").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution of this one few times ago but forgot to post it. I just add this line in my ajax request success case `jQuery( "form[data-role='tocart-form']" ).catalogAddToCart();`

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function($){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/whoboughtthisproduct/index/getproducts",
        type: "POST",
        data: "prod=<?php echo $productId; ?>",
        success: function (res) {
            if(res.indexOf("find products matching the selection") > -1){
                //if no products found then do nothing
                return;
            }

            var result = jQuery('.product-items', res).html();
            jQuery(".bought-slider").html(result);
            jQuery( "form[data-role='tocart-form']" ).catalogAddToCart();
        }
    });
});
```

I hope it help others who is facing the same kind of problem.

Comment: mmmm, not sure about this... catalogAddToCart() as a jQuery function?

Comment: this code showing error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).catalogAddToCart is not a function. How to solve this?

Comment: require(['jquery','domReady!','Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart'], function ($) {

                jQuery( "form[data-role='tocart-form']" ).catalogAddToCart();

            });

Comment: Thank you this is working for me.